# Specify app with heroku db:push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I often do `heroku db:pull` and it works great.

I have created a staging app, to review code changes on Heroku before deploying to the production app.

I wonder though how I push db data specifically to the staging app?

Will the follwing work? `heroku db:push -a my-staging-app-name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
heroku db:push -a my-staging-app-name
```

will only push your local data to heroku.  but it has some problems

I suggest you to push production db directly to staging server

For that you need to get the URL from production and run following command.

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'db_dump_url' -a my-staging-app-name
```

Comment: Actually `heroku db:push` seems even deprecated (by heroku pg:push perhaps?), so thanks a lot for the much useful alternative!